# Pyspark Dataframe - Counting baklog each last day of the month

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, count, backlog

I'm trying to looking for a solution to one problem. I've the following df:

| task | open_date | close_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t01 | 05/03/2021 | 16/03/2021 |
| t02 | 07/03/2021 | 13/04/2021 |
| t03 | 23/03/2021 | 04/04/2021 |

I need a new df with the backlog at the end of the month (opened that month and closed after it):

| end_of_month | backlog |
| --- | --- |
| 31/03/2021 | 2 |

I'm playing with last_day() to get the EOM but I'm not reaching with the query/code to getting the right count. Could you help me?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    df
    .withColumn('open_month_next_month', add_months('open_date', 1))
    .filter(last_day('open_month_next_month') == last_day('close_date'))
    .withColumn('end_of_month', last_day('open_date'))
    .groupBy('end_of_month')
    .agg(F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('backlog'))
```

Comment: Hi NaWeeD, thanks for the answer but I guess that only works if the close date is the next month but could be after 2 or more months.

Comment: @David Well I guess you should only change the `==` to `<=` right?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data = [("t01", "05/03/2021", "16/03/2021"),
        ("t02", "07/03/2021", "13/04/2021"),
        ("t03", "23/03/2021", "04/04/2021"),
        ("t04", "07/03/2021", "13/05/2021"),
        ("t05", "23/03/2021", "04/05/2021")]
schema = ["TaskID", "TaskstartDate", "TaskEndDate"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df = df.withColumn("TaskstartDate",F.to_date(F.col("TaskstartDate"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))\
.withColumn("TaskEndDate",F.to_date(F.col("TaskEndDate"), "dd/MM/yyyy"))

df_grouped = df.withColumn("EndDay_fromStartDate", F.last_day(F.col("TaskstartDate")))\
.withColumn("EndDay_fromEndDate", F.last_day(F.col("TaskEndDate")))\
.filter((F.col("EndDay_fromStartDate") != F.col("EndDay_fromEndDate")) & (F.col("TaskstartDate") < F.col("TaskEndDate")))\
.groupBy('EndDay_fromStartDate')\
.agg(F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('backlog'))

df_grouped.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Kris! I think this is exactly what I need. I'll try it and I'll mark it as the solution if it works properly.

Comment: Finally, it isn't working at all. When I've a task which was opened on March an closed on June, it's only appearing in March's backlog and must appear also in April and May.